# how to use y_true/y_test and y_pred?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, python-3.6, metrics

in this line I used y_true and y_pred:

```
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=[precision(y_true,y_pred),recall(y_true,y_pred),fmeasure(y_true,y_pred)])
```

but a this error happened:

> NameError: name 'y_true' is not defined

and I imported metrics

```
from keras import metrics
```

Comment: It appears you have not declared it, can you share more of your code then it will be easier to explain

Comment: I thought that they are variables in `metrics`, how can I define them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When specifying metrics, you pass function objects to the metrics parameter, not function calls. There is no need at all to mention `y_true` and `y_pred`:

```
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=[precision, recall, fmeasure])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I wrote the functions between double quotations , that is way it didn't work with me. Thank you!